# Where is index.html in an embedded directory?

Tags: go, webserver, single-page-application

I am trying to [embed](https://golang.org/pkg/embed/) a static site (and SPA) into my Go code. The high level structure of my project is

```
.
├── web.go
└── spa/
    └── index.html
```

My intent is to have `http://localhost:8090/` serving `index.html`.

The relevant code to do that is

```
//go:embed spa
var spa embed.FS

log.Info("starting api server")
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.FS(spa)))
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8090", r))
```

When accessing `http://localhost:8090/`, I get

- a directory listing page with a single link `spa`
- upon clicking on this link I get a `404 page not found`

How should I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Gorilla Mux you need to specify a path prefix:

```
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

//go:embed spa
var spa embed.FS

func main() {
    log.Println("starting api server")
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.PathPrefix("/spa/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.FS(spa))))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8090", r))
}
```

This will route requests to `<host>/spa/*` to the handler. Then you must strip the prefix `/` as the contents of `spa` directory have the `spa/` prefix without the leading `/`:

```
    b, _ := spa.ReadFile("spa/index.html")
    fmt.Println(string(b)) // file contents
```

To wrap it up:

`http://localhost:8090/spa/index.html` is routed to the `r.PathPrefix("/spa/")` handler. The route though is `/spa/index.html`, strip the first `/` resulting in `spa/index.html` and this finally matches the file path in the embedded variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. It works in the sense that `http://localhost:8090/spa/` ultimately reaches the `index.html` file and the URI is `http://localhost:8090/spa/#/` (and the content is fully visible). Thanks a lot for that. I will read about how to redirect `/` to `/spa/` in order to have the root serving the SPA.

Answer (score 13):

File paths in an embedded directory are prefixed by the path used in the //go:embed directive. The embedded file system path for index.html is ​`spa/index.html`.

[Create a sub file system](https://pkg.go.dev/io/fs#Sub) rooted at the `spa` directory and serve that file system. The path for `index.html` in the sub file system is `index.html`.

```
sub, _ := fs.Sub(spa, "spa")
r.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.FS(sub)))
```

https://pkg.go.dev/io/fs#Sub

[Run an example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RE7uz7-FsAA).

This approach works with any mux including the Gorilla Mux.  Here's the code for Gorilla where `r` is a `*mux.Router`:

```
sub, _ := fs.Sub(spa, "spa")
r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.FS(sub)))
```

[Run an example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/R7z5MliBooM)

Comment: Thank you. I must investigate that because when going from @blackgreen's solution to yours (`r.PathPrefix("/spa/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.FS(spa))))` → `r.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.FS(sub)))`), the call to `index.html` is correct, but then all consecutive call fail (either with a 404 or with `(canceled)`), which is really strange (on the same `spa` directory)

Comment: What do you mean by "all consecutive call"?  Are you saying that the second request to `/index.html` fails, the request to some other url fails?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. What I meant is that `index.html` calls other URLs (it is an SPA), and these calls (to files in the created FS, next to `index.html`) fail with 404 or `(cancelled)` (per Chrome DevTools). What is weird is that the other solution works fine with the same files, at the same place (but of course called with the `/spa` suffix)

Comment: @WoJ I updated the answer to show how to match the tree rooted at "/" using Gorilla Mux.

Comment: Does it depend on the spa directory at run time?